# Twilio attach statusCallbackEvent and url on an incoming call

Tags: twilio, twilio-php

I am trying to forward a call to user phone if his twilio phone is called.

```
$usr_ph = 'xxxxxxxxxx'; // get user personal phone from database
$twiml = new Twiml();
$twiml->dial($usr_ph);
return $twiml;
```

The above code works fine , I need to get the call minutes. So I added status callback url to dial . But its not sending me the any status event

Below is the code I have

```
$data = array ('statusCallbackEvent' => array('completed'),
    statusCallback' => "https://mywebsite.com/get_Call_outcome",
    'statusCallbackMethod' => 'POST'
   );

$twiml = new Twiml();
$twiml->dial($usr_ph, json_encode($data));
return $twiml;
```

I did tried :

```
$twiml = new Twiml();
$twiml->dial($usr_ph, [
'statusCallbackEvent' => array('completed'),
'statusCallback' => "https://mywebsite.com/get_Call_outcome",
'statusCallbackMethod' => 'POST'
]);
return $twiml;
```

But then I get the error message as

```
SimpleXMLElement::addAttribute() expects parameter 2 to be string, array given
```

Not sure , but I think I need to add statusCallbackEvent on the original call which was made on the twilio phone.

Edit:

Now I tried updating the incoming call by adding  statusCallbackEvent, but its still not sending any Event.

```
$twi = new Client($twilio->sid, $twilio->token);
$call = $twi->calls($request->input('CallSid'))
        ->update(array ('statusCallbackEvent' => array('completed'),
                 'statusCallback' =>"www.mywebsite.com/get_Call_outcome",
                 'statusCallbackMethod' => 'POST'
         ));
```

Answer (score 0):

The statusCallback is part of the Number noun, not Dial verb. You can find more details below. See if that addresses the issue.

Twilio Voice: 
https://www.twilio.com/docs/voice/twiml/number

Comment: I am trying to attach statusCallbackEvent and url on an incoming call. I tried  modifying the incoming  call on the sid but its not working either. While I can attach statusCallbackEvent  om an outgoing call while making the call

Comment: Where you set up the Voice URL for your Twilio Number, enable statusCallBacks there.

Comment: Yes, I got help from Twilio Support, they said to setup url in "CALL STATUS CHANGES" on the dashboard. Thanks for your help @Alan

Answer (score 0):

**Try this Set Status Codes on Number Noune**

```
$dial->number('+14158675310', [
    'statusCallbackEvent' => 'initiated ringing answered completed',
    'statusCallback' => 'https://myapp.com/calls/events',
    'statusCallbackMethod' => 'POST'
]);
```